# Android Studio and layouts

Tags: android-studio-3.6, android-studio-3.6.1

The Android Studio 3.6 Starts with a Constraint Layout as default when opening an empty activity app. How can I Change it to relative Layout and set is as default maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways:
1) select layout name and change to RelativeLayout

2)go to 
app->res->layout->right click for new layout resourse ->change in root element to RelaytiveLayout->finish